# Pokémon wondertraded to ORAS do not appear in pokédex

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I received a few new pokémon over wondertrade, but they did not update to my pokédex.

For example, before the wondertrade, my pokédex seen count was at 23. After receiving new pokémon, the count is still at 23.

Do I have to catch the pokémon myself, or should wondertrade count towards my pokédex?

Comment: For a start it would help to have relevant information.. what pokemon are you missing, for one

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: The pokemon aren't missing, they just don't show up in my pokedex.

Comment: how far have you progressed in the game? The answer is yes, wondertrade counts towards pokedex, but I think I know what your problem is, too. It would also help if you could tell us what pokemon you recieved from wondertrade.

Comment: I am only in the town with the rock gym. I can't think of the pokemon I got.

Comment: I feel someone else will answer this better then me, but Im gathering your fairly early on, and this should still answer your question.

Comment: Thanks! I get what you are saying about thE different pokedexs. I think you are correct because some if the pokemon I got had a ??? As the dex number.

Comment: As it turns out, I remember this from playing the same version. Updating my answer with how to get the national pokedex, incase it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wonder-trading pokémon should count towards Pokédex completion. [I confirmed this at GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67617129), where a user asks if they can use Wondertrade to complete their Pokédex.

That said, you do not start the game with a National Pokédex, which is needed to identify all the available pokémon. A Pokédex typically represents a region, and with the amount of pokémon available in the newer generations, a game can include multiple regions. In Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire, you start with a Hoenn Pokédex, which only holds a fraction of the pokémon available.

If you capture a pokémon that is not found in the Pokédex you currently have, it will not count towards completion or be otherwise view able until you have acquired a National Pokédex.

> **To quote the [IGN page](http://au.ign.com/) on [the pokédex in Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire](http://au.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire/Pokedex),**
>
> After defeating the Pokemon League, the Pokedex will be upgraded to the National Pokedex (sometimes called National Dex), which lists the Pokemon in the original order from 1 - 719.
>
> ... The Hoenn Pokedex features a total of 211 Pokemon.